# Understanding a proof about a Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

> Let $X$ be Poisson distributed where $P(X=n) = p_n(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$ for $n \geq 0$. Show
>   $$P(x \leq n) = 1 - \int_0^\lambda P_n(x) dx.$$

This is the argument given:

$\frac{d}{d\lambda} p_n = p_{n-1} - p_n$ where $p_{-1} = 0$. Hence 
$$(\frac{d}{d \lambda})P(X \leq n) = p_n(\lambda).$$

Can someone please explain this argument better, because I am understanding nothing at all.

Comment: Which step is unclear?

Comment: Actually i am not understanding the reasoning at all. To be more precise, why $(\frac{d}{d \lambda})P(X \leq n) = p_n(\lambda)$ and how can this solve the problem.

Comment: 1. Find $\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\right)$ and compare this with $p_{n-1}(\lambda)-p_{n}(\lambda)$

Comment: 2. $P(X \le n)= p_{0}(\lambda)+p_{1}(\lambda) +\cdots + p_{n}(\lambda)$.  Take the derivative of both sides of this with respect to $\lambda$, using the previous result, and telescope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct formula should be

$$\tag{1}(\frac{d}{d \lambda})P(X \leq n) = -p_n(\lambda).$$

(with a minus sign in the RHS). The proof of (1) is as follows:

Let us apply the classical rule $d(fg)/d\lambda=(df/d\lambda).g+f.(dg/d\lambda)$ to the formula:

$$p_n(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$$

We get:

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} p_n = n\dfrac{\lambda^{n-1}}{n!}e^{-\lambda} + \dfrac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}(-e^{-\lambda})=\dfrac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda} - \dfrac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}=p_{n-1} - p_n  \ \ \ \text{(property} \ P_n)$$

Thus, adding the equations of properties $P_0, P_1, \cdots P_n$, one obtains (because of concellations in the RHS):

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}(p_0+p_1+\cdots+p_n)=p_0-p_n=-p_n$$

proving (1) because the LHS is nothing but $p_0+p_1+\cdots+p_n=P(X \leq n)$.

Edit : (following a good remark of @Henry) How convention

$$\tag{2}p_{-1}=0$$

can be explained ? Let us have a look at case $n=0$ :

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda} p_0 = \frac{d}{d\lambda} e^{-\lambda}=-e^{-\lambda}=-p_0=p_{-1}-p_0$$

if one takes convention (2).

Edit (following another remark of @Henry) : Let us establish the first relationship written under the following form (with a capital $X$ and a more neutral variable "$u$" in the integral):

$$\tag{3}P(X \leq n) = 1 - \int_0^\lambda P_n(u) du.$$

Here is a proof; clearly, from (1), one can deduce :

$$\tag{4}P(X \leq n) = K - \int_0^\lambda P_n(u) du$$

for a certain constant $K$ (this kind of additive constant appears whenever a primitive function is taken on both sides of an equality). The question is now, comparing (3) and (4) : why do we have $K=1$ ?

In fact, there is an explicit expression for the integral in (4) (see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)):

$$\tag{5}\int_0^\lambda P_n(u) du=\int_0^\lambda \frac{u^n}{n!}e^{-u} du=\left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{u^k}{k!}\right)e^{-u}\right]_{u=0}^{u=\lambda}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\right)e^{-\lambda}-1$$

Plugging this result into (4), one gets

$$\tag{6}P(X\leq n)=K+\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\right)e^{-\lambda}-1$$

When $n \rightarrow \infty$, for any fixed value of $\lambda$,

- the LHS of (6) tends to $1$,
- the RHS of (6) tends to $K+e^{\lambda}e^{-\lambda}-1=K+1-1=K$ (due to the series expansion of "exp" function).

explaining why $K=1.$

Comment: I suspect you need $p_{-1}(\lambda)=0$ somewhere, and perhaps also $P(X \le n) = 1$ when  $\lambda=0$

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Henry. Concerning the explanation about $p_{-1}(\lambda)=0$, you are right, I am going to make an edit to my answer. I should have said that a particular case occurs at the beginning :$\frac{d}{d\lambda} p_0 = \frac{d}{d\lambda} e^{-\lambda}=-e^{-\lambda}=-p_0=p_{-1}-p_0$ if one takes the convention $p_{-1}=0$. But, I don't understand your second remark : for me, the case $\lambda=0$ never occurs for Poisson distribution.

Comment: Where does the $1$ come from in  $\displaystyle 1 - \int_0^\lambda P_n(x) dx$ ?

Comment: @Henry: Your question is interesting and deserves also an "edit" to my answer.  I am going to do it (I had just not adressed this issue because it was not asked by the OP). In short, this "1" is an additive constant the kind of which appears whenever a primitive function is taken on both sides of an equality. But why "1" ?

Comment: Perhaps $\displaystyle \int_0^\lambda p_n(x) dx = \left. -P_x(X \le n) {\, \atop \,} \right|_{x=0}^{x=\lambda}= -P_\lambda(X \le n) + P_0(X \le n)$.  Then rearrange to $\displaystyle   P_\lambda(X \le n) = P_0(X \le n)- \int_0^\lambda p_n(x) dx$  and use $P_0(X \le n)=1$.

Comment: But a constant $K$ should be introduced in $\displaystyle \int_0^\lambda p_n(x) dx = \left. -P_x(X \le n) {\, \atop \,} \right|_{x=0}^{x=\lambda}+K=\cdots$. See the edit to my answer I just wrote.

Comment: I suspect that you do not need a constant of integration for a definite integral (as if you add it then you will also subtract it).  No matter

Comment: In fact, it should not be considered a definite integral, for the following reason: there is arbitrariness in the choice of the lower bound $0$. Thus constant $K$ "compensates" this arbitrariness.

Comment: No need to respond further.  My view is that an almost-surely-constant-zero random variable, i.e. with $P(X=0)=1$, can be described as a Poisson random variable with $\lambda=0$, and that leads to $P_0(X \le n)=1$ here.  You seem to be less comfortable with that.

Comment: @Henry Thanks very much for pointing that. I had never considered this limit case.